# laravel and phpunit: could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laragon

I have run my laravel app with phpunit.
Everything is fine until at some point when I run my test again turns out with this error.

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)
```

[image]

```
Caused by
PDOException: could not find driver
```

Here's my phpunit.xml file:

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
     bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
     colors="true">
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Unit">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="Feature">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
<filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
<php>
    <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
    <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
    <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
    <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
    <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
</php>
```

```
OS: Windows 10 | php version: PHP 7.4.11 | sqlite version: SQLite version 3.19.1
```

Does anyone encounter with this error in laravel 6 and phpunit?

Comment: can you please post more information? Like your phpunit.xml file. Are you using sqlite?

Comment: Yes I'm using sqlite and database value as memory. Please refer my updated post @JonathanMartins

Comment: Whats you OS? Whats the PHP version? do you have the sqlite driver installed?

Comment: Yup I have sqlite installed. Updated my post as per your questions.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is actually happening after I upgraded my php version in laragon. The solution is to enable pdo_sqlite on php extension in laragon. That's it. This answer found here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/phpunit-sqlite-error-after-updating-laragon-pdoexception-could-not-find-driver

Comment: Glad that you find the solution to your problem.

Comment: Yup happy to find the solution

Comment: It worked. Do not forget to stop and start all services

Answer (score 71):

If You face this problem

> (could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;))

You can simply run bellow command on your Ubuntu system

```
sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3
```

Also if you want to install specific version like php 8.1 simply run bellow command

```
sudo apt install php8.1-sqlite3
```

You might need to enable pdo_sqlite extension in your php.ini too, you can get the path of your loaded ini with the below command:

```
php --ini
```

simply add extension=pdo_sqlite to your php.ini and verify it is loaded by running

```
php -m | grep pdo_sqlite
```

**I think it will help you.. Thanks**

Comment: For `php8.1` the package is `php8.1-sqlite3`.

Comment: Editing php.ini solved my issue

Answer (score 10):

### PHP 8.1

`sudo apt install php8.1-sqlite3`

Note that it needs the 8.1 part!

Answer (score 5):

This happens because PDO Sqlite is not enabled.
to enable it in Laragon, just open Laragon click on menu > PHP > Extensions > pdo_sqlite That's it.

And if you don't use Laragon the solution might be different. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For those using windows;

Navigate to the php.ini file(-C:\php\php.ini)

Enable the following:

```
;extension=pdo_sqlite by removing the /;/ should look like this extension=pdo_sqlite

;extension=sqlite3 should be extension=sqlite3 without the ; symbol
```

Comment: Path to that ini file isn't necessarily always that `C:\php\php.ini` and can depend on your installation. You can run `php --ini` command in your terminal to get path to ini file for your current active PHP installation.

Answer (score 4):

just enabling these two extension from php.ini file worked for me.

```
extension=pdo_sqlite

extension=sqlite3
```

Answer (score 4):

If you come across such an error,simply do the following;

1.run this command to install sqlite driver in your ubuntu or linux OS

```
sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3
```

2. You also need to enable *pdo_sqlite* extension in your *php.ini* too, check the path of your loaded *.ini* with the below command

   php --ini

3.Then check and verify that the pdo_sqlite extension is loaded.

```
php -m | grep pdo_sqlite
```

Then the error will be solved.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Ubuntu try this:

```bash
php --version
sudo apt-get install PHP (your php version)-sqlite3
```

This works for me.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sqlite-database-throw-error-could-not-find-driver-sql-pragma-foreign-keys-on

Comment: It's very important to check if your version of PHP CLI first, php.ini might be load a different version so.. you should match phpx.y-sqlite3 packege

Answer (score 2):

**Just do the following changes on the php.ini file**

```
extension_dir = "<php installation directory>/php-7.4.3/ext"
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
sqlite3.extension_dir = "<php installation directory>/php-7.4.3/ext"
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if you have multiple versions of PHP in Laragon you will still see the error.
**The solution is to enable pdo_sqlite extension on all versions.**
The reason is that Laragon has its own PHP but Laravel uses the system PHP and you might not know which one is system PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

At first uncomment `;extension=pdo_sqlite` in `php.ini` in `/etc/php/{your_php_version}/php.ini` on Linux or `C:\php\php.ini` on Windows by removing the semicolon at the beginning.

then  `sudo service apache2 restart`

then `sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3`

Answer (score 0):

**You need to install sqlite3 package in linux distro**

```
sudo apt-get install php$(php -r 'echo PHP_MAJOR_VERSION.".".PHP_MINOR_VERSION;')-sqlite3  php-sqlite3
```

This command automatically install the sqlite3 package based on your current PHP version in your Linux distro.