# php artisan migrate not working when trying to set up sqlite database

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

I have just cloned a laravel project I was working on, into a new machine. I have re-installed all the dependencies, including sqlite and re-configured the database details in the .env file. However, when I try to run php artisan migrate, I get the following error:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:759
    755▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    756▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    757▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    758▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 759▕             throw new QueryException(
    760▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    761▕             );
    762▕         }
    763▕     }

  1   C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("could not find driver")

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\Soko\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct()
```

What could be the problem?

Here is my .env file

```
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=sqlite

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
```

I had already come across a similar question. And I have tried going to my php.ini file, there are two apparently, one for development and the other for production. I have edited them both, by removing the semicolon in (;extension=pdo_sqlite.dll) and (;extension=sqlite3). I have also tried to tab them out, but as per the comments, nothing has worked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64381185/laravel-and-phpunit-could-not-find-driver-sql-pragma-foreign-keys-on

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel and phpunit: could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign\_keys = ON;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64381185/laravel-and-phpunit-could-not-find-driver-sql-pragma-foreign-keys-on)

Comment: I had already come across that solution. And I have tried going to my php.ini file, there are two apparently, one for development and the other for production. I have edited them both, by removing the semicolon in (;extension=pdo_sqlite.dll) and (;extension=sqlite3). I have also tried to tab them out, as per the comments, nothing has worked.

Comment: So there are actually three php.ini files. For windows that is. And that's what's confusing. There is one for development, another for production and now the main one. To be safe you need to change the main one, or all three. Thats what worked for me

Answer (score 1):

1. check file `.env` exist and the same name.
2. check in `.env` file database name and configuration exist.
3. check database exist in SQLite.
4. check command `php artisan` return all Laravel commands, if doesn't work execute `composer i`.
5. then check the error: `could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)`.

Comment: I have added my .env file. I had already set the database to SQLite. All PHP commands are running fine. As for number 5, how do I check that? I think the issue is that it's still pointing to the SQL server instead of the SQLite one, I don't know why

Comment: really I'm not using SQLite